# No route matches [GET] "/assets/bootstrap.css.map"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm running on rails4, bootstrap 3 and I get the following error message in my terminal.

```
Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.css.map" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-24 23:41:36 -0700

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/bootstrap.css.map"):
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'


railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
```

Anyone have any ideas how to get rid of this?

EDIT:

This is my application.css

> *= require_tree .
>   *= require_self
>   *= require_ladda-themeless
>   *= require login_form
>   *= require bootstrap
>   */

Comment: Could you post your layout file and your application.css(.scss)? Where did you placed the bootstrap files?

Comment: how have you tried to include `bootstrap.css.map`?

Comment: No... I've never seen it included in other people's apps. @Victor, my bootstrap files (bootstrap.js, bootstrap.min.js, bootstrap.css, bootstrap.min.css) are included in app/assets/javascripts, app/assets/stylesheets respectively.

Comment: I assume you are using a gem. What bootstrap gem is it?

Comment: `*= require_tree .` use at the last in the list.

Comment: @nithin, unfortunately, that didn't fix the problem...

Answer (score 46):

The file that requests the `bootstrap.css.map` is:

`/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.css`

And removing this last line should fix the problem:

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.css.map */
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21504707/2087198) what are map files used for.

Comment: You could also just extract the appropriate file from [the bootstrap download](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/#download).

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and found this [short answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23909455/438270) on SO. From what I understand the map files are an aid to debugging tools in the browser. Quick fix is to find where this map file is included, by issuing a command line find.

```
find . -name "*.css" -o -name "*.scss" | xargs grep 'sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.css.map'
```

Then either delete the line from your css file or move it to where it will be looking for it.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, so instead of having native bootstrap files under the app/assets folder, I just created custom.css.scss under app/assets/stylesheets and included `@import "bootstrap";`
Then, I removed all the bootstrap files from app/assets folder which solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

my error: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/bootstrap.min.css.map"):

I created an empty bootstrap.min.css.map in assets folder, the error stopped.