# Failed to load resource Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, browser, local

I linked the newest version of `bootstrap.min.css` with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">` to my webpage.
Everything worked fine. But now my browser tell me that the `bootstrap.min.css.map` is failed to load.

My stylesheet link says that `bootstrap.min.css` is linked, not the `.map`

With `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">` everything works fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap trying to load map file. How to disable it? Do I need to do it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21773376/bootstrap-trying-to-load-map-file-how-to-disable-it-do-i-need-to-do-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable it with deleting "/*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.min.css.map */" from your bootstrap.css file.

The warning should disappear.