# Is bootstrap.css.map taking 80% of my site's bandwidth?

Tags: performance, twitter-bootstrap-3, webserver

I know what `bootstrap.css.map` is and how to remove it. My question is different.

Is this file being loaded on normal customers' browsers, or does it only get pulled in when I open Chrome Developer Console?

Answer (score 1):

Basically map files are for developers. It is not required on production machines.
You could go through following answer on stack overflow this will help you understand concept better.

[Bootstrap trying to load map file. How to disable it? Do I need to do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21773376/bootstrap-trying-to-load-map-file-how-to-disable-it-do-i-need-to-do-it)

Comment: One more link  https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/source-maps