# Twitter Bootstrap plugin in Grails has errors

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grails, less, grails-plugin

I'm building my first Grails Application and I followed the tutorial on how to install the twitter-bootstrap-grails-plugin; (https://github.com/groovydev/twitter-bootstrap-grails-plugin/blob/master/README.md)

I followed the instructions there until I reached the Less plugin installation. For starts I just want to use the default distribution of Bootstrap UI.

The problem I encounter is that whenever a page is loaded I get this error in the server:

2014-02-24 17:56:48,556 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /bootstrap.css.map

Even though the first page I've tried it on seems to work, I wonder what's the .map file? Is it so important? And why it doens't work since it is there in the plugin distribution..

thanks in advance!

Comment: These are mapping files for compressed sources which help dev tools debugging: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504611/what-are-the-map-files-used-for-in-bootstrap-3-1 It's not a must to have them for your code to work. Can't you just add them your self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newer versions of the twitter-bootstrap plugin are configured for the grails resource managment plugin `asset-pipeline` which has a distinct way of minifying and packaging .css files.

If you still prefer to manage resources with the `resources` plugin you can avoid this error by adding

```
    grails.plugins.twitterbootstrap.defaultBundle = false
```

to your Config.goovy.