# Remove zombie .less files from Workspace in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome-devtools

Help! I can't delete these files from the Dev Workspace:

[image]

- *Right click → Delete file* brings up a modal dialog, but when I click *Ok* nothing happens.
- These files don't exist anywhere — I deleted them from Explorer hours ago
- I cleared my browser cache
- I didn't add the files manually. I think they may have been added by the [Tincr extension](http://tin.cr/)
- I'm not running any extensions currently
- In fact, I deleted my Chrome profile folder and re-installed Chrome (v 33.0.1750.154 m)
- Yes, I rebooted
- These zombie files won't die

P.S. I assure you the files do not exist:

[image]

P.P.S. The reason why I need them gone is that they're showing up as active CSS rules in the Elements tab, which is making it impossible to debug CSS issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The files in question didn't exist per se, but they did exist in a form: they had been compiled into `*.map` files: `bootstrap.css.map` and `bootstrap-theme.css.map`. Deleting the `*.map` files removes the zombie `*.less` files from Chrome Dev Tools. Yay for magic files that get out of sync with the codebase.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21504707/27581) for an explanation of the purpose of `*.map` files.