# debug with scss instead of css in inspect element

Tags: sass

I know how to work with source map with the source tab in chrome. But I would to debug it just  like the css appear in the element tab in chrome on the right side.

Is this possible to get style.scss instead of style.css while inspecting? 
The reason I am asking this is.

With source tab whenever I made changes I have to find the lines and code to edit. After you find it you need to update css properties and save the file. To view the result you must refresh.
That's a big problem.

I have heard about style.css.map. What it is exactly? how it can help debug?
I have read below stackoverflow question. I still don't understand. Maybe am unknown with basic rule. 
[What are .map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504611/what-are-the-map-files-used-for-in-bootstrap-3-1)

Is it necessary to have only `sass-3.3.0.alpha.103` version of sass. Because I think I have updated one.
My sass version is `sass 3.3.8 (Maptastic Maple)` Is this compatible with sourcemap or I have to install 'sass-3.3.0.alpha.103' strictly ?

Can I use `sourcemap` with `compass` ? I always use compass to compile my sass project because it provides several mixins and easily creates sprites. I love this. Below is the line I use to compile my sass with compass command

```
compass watch folder-name
```

But the tutorial is showing `sass watch` method of compiling scss files.
[tutorial to use source map](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/developing-with-sass-and-chrome-devtools--net-32805)

```
sass --watch --scss --sourcemap styles.scss:styles.css
```

Is this necessary for me to use above sass watch to work with sourcemap ? 
Please describe in some more details.

Thanks in advance.

Please help