# ExecJS::ProgramError: /bootstrap-theme.css.map:1:14: Unknown word

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, assets

rails 4.1.7
ruby-2.1.4

Using  bootstrap-sass 3.3.1.0 gem

When I try to push to Heroku I get the following error:

```
$ git push heroku master
...
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       I, [2014-11-21T01:06:34.863128 #1054]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_5e094815d056adf463e7c75e987d5e63/public/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular-3ba17edd9d971727ac7482518167c417.eot
       I, [2014-11-21T01:06:34.865429 #1054]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_5e094815d056adf463e7c75e987d5e63/public/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular-9fdfa71474063341410181a0580f8cc9.svg
       I, [2014-11-21T01:06:34.867462 #1054]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_5e094815d056adf463e7c75e987d5e63/public/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular-b1be6b5ab502863bf4997057c9e81c47.ttf
       I, [2014-11-21T01:06:34.869377 #1054]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_5e094815d056adf463e7c75e987d5e63/public/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular-d1bdcb334cbe33c43cd1644d34c214bc.woff
       I, [2014-11-21T01:06:39.656791 #1054]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_5e094815d056adf463e7c75e987d5e63/public/assets/application-16641e09fe68375d82a616882c87cd48.js
       rake aborted!
       ExecJS::ProgramError: /bootstrap-theme.css.map:1:14: Unknown word
...
```

On my config/application.rb file I have:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Evolution
  class Application < Rails::Application

    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

  end
end
```

Any idea how to fix this error?

---

UPDATE #1

If I search for the word "bootstrap-theme" in the App directory, I find:

4 matches across 2 files:

```
/Users/andreucasadella/rails_projects/evolution/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-theme.css:
  468            box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  469  }
  470: /*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap-theme.css.map */
```

And

```
/Users/andreucasadella/rails_projects/evolution/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-theme.css.map:
    1: {"version":3,"sources":["less/theme.less","less/mixins/vendor-prefixes.less","bootstrap-theme.css","less/mixins/gradients.less","less/mixins/reset-filter.less"],"names":...
```

I understand that the "Unknown word" is on the file /bootstrap-theme.css.map and on line 1:14.

How do I identify space 14?

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to find an answer, therefore I decided to delete both map files:
- bootstrap-theme.css.map
- bootstrap.css.map

I will not be able live-edit my preprocessor source files in the DevTools Sources panel, but at least I can go on. Hope to find a better answer soon.

[what are the .map files used for in Bootstrap 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504611/what-are-the-map-files-used-for-in-bootstrap-3-1)

Comment: I've solved problem for me. 

Bootstrap was installed by Bower in Rails app. I've removed bootstrap folder from vendor folder and run  ```bower install```.

Good Luck! :)