# Understanding Bootstrap and jquery in Asp.net

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

So i have just figured out how to download the NuGet packages and i installed the bootstrap and jquery packages, but now im a little lost, when i used bootstrap before, i only had bootstrap.min.js, and the same with the css and my costume ones that i referenced.

so now what is this used for : jquery-2.1.3.intellisense.js ? 
also what is the npm.js ? it came with the jquery package.

Here is an Image of the Npm file content

[image]

if anyone could help me understand the .theme and .map correctly for css and the .map for js, that would be great. From what i can gather from what iv read, .Map is used for bootstrap 2* and .theme is just their themes, am i on the right track ?

The Fonts folder, are those automatically used or do they have to be references ? and how are they used ?

heres an image of my folders:

[image]

Comment: i want to thank 'timothclifford' as he took the time to help and even though this post is very broad, i understand it all now, so thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**.intellisense.js** files are for Visual Studio, they extend the default intellisense (auto complete options) you get out of the box. So the jQuery.intellisense.js will provide additional intellisense options when you're using jQuery. Mads Kristensen is probably the best resource on this topic: http://madskristensen.net/post/improved-javascript-intellisense-in-visual-studio

**.map** files are JavaScript source maps. These allow browsers to de-minify your scripts so you can more easily debug them. More detail here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/

**bootstrap-theme.css** is an optional theme you can apply to Bootstrap, you don't have to reference it.

**The fonts and icons** are referenced in the bootstrap.css so you don't need to reference these explicitly.

Comment: Wouw thanks alot man, that was very help full. So do i have to actroly reference the .intellisense.js ?

Comment: Hi there, sorry man i found a microsoft source on it, thanks for the great help

Comment: You're welcome. No you don't need to reference the intellisense.js file, Visual Studio will include this so long as it exists.

Comment: So its mostly for Ajax based Tasks ? like you mentioned The autocomplete, so would this be used along with the Ajax autocomplete control  ?

Comment: No sorry. When I say auto-complete, I mean when you're typing in Visual Studio. Intellisense are the suggestions you see when you're typing. An example of what I mean http://madskristensen.net.m82.be/posts/files/6617b7ba-0c90-4d99-9daf-892992133d89.png

Comment: Oww i see, hahahaha that makes perfect sens, i miss read that one sorry, Thanks again for your time and Help Have a good one :)

Comment: Do you know anything about the npm.js ?

Comment: Haven't seen before but I can take a look. What version of Visual Studio and project template are you using?

Comment: Im using visual studio 2013 express for web, and i just created a project, selected asp.net web aplication and then selected empty from the Template. Then i right clicked on the solution name and selected Manage nuget packages, then installed bootstrap and jquery,

Comment: Hmm I don't have that version unfortunately sorry... Can you add the content of that file to the question please?

Comment: What do you mean man ?

Comment: Open the npm.js file, copy and paste the contents into your question and I'll see if I can figure out what it is :)

Comment: i Added an image of the Content, please review

Comment: Ah OK. That file is related to Bootstrap, it's just referencing all the additional JavaScript components you can potentially include. You don't need to reference or worry about it.

Comment: Alright Great man, thanks for all your help, i know this was a long commenting session lol, but thanks for your time and assistance :)

Answer (score 2):

> so now what is this used for : jquery-2.1.3.intellisense.js ? also
>   what is the npm.js ? it cam with the jquery package.

npm is a file from Node.js: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap

Regarding Intellisense, I'm not quite sure why it is included. But might be regarding some parsing of, for example, class attributes.

> if anyone could help me understand the .theme and .map correctly for
>   css and the .map for js, that would be great

The theme map is indeed the 'theming'. Regarding the .map folder, I'd suggest reading this topic:

[what are the .map files used for in Bootstrap 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504611/what-are-the-map-files-used-for-in-bootstrap-3-1)

> The Fonts folder, are those automatically used or do they have to be
>   references ? and how are they used ?

Yes, the listed fonts are automatically used. They are referenced to by the bootstrap stylesheets.

For example, when viewing the css: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css

You would see:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: Thanks man for the feed back, so what is npm.js for then ? i had a look at it and it just has a bunch of requires like this : require('../../js/transition.js') , So do i need to reference it then ?