# With no physical .less files in project, how does Bootstrap show .less stuff in Chrome inspector?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm really confused about LESS, which is still new to me. Bootstrap uses it, and I can see references to it in Chrome's style inspector, making references to a grid-framework.less file, but when I go looking on the hard drive for it in my project, it's not there. How is that even possible? When I did a grep followed by cut command to find which file was referencing grid-framework.less, I found it was in two files: bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css.map and bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css.map. And there, as well, I have no idea what .map files are either. I have much to learn.

So, in general, please explain what .map files are, and then explain how these load the .less file, and then explain how .less files are loaded in the browser, and how far back do browsers go before they won't process .less stuff from Bootstrap 3?

Comment: [Please check this question out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504611/what-are-the-map-files-used-for-in-bootstrap-3-1)