# How to put .map file in HTML document?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to put some Bootstrap code in website, I found some scripts, in file there are files with `.map` extension. I don't know how to upload them in HTML document. We connect CSS file from HTML file with following tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/wp-content/themes/heatmap-adaptive.1.5.3/style.css"/>
```

and so, how can do some job with .map?

There are files with such names: `bootstrap-theme.min.css.map`

Comment: If not a dup, maybe still good to know. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504611/what-are-the-map-files-used-for-in-bootstrap-3-1

Comment: okey but how to put it in html code?

Comment: You don't. Please read the answers on the above linked post.

Answer (score 6):

Those are source map files, they are used for debugging the CSS code after it has been minified. The browser reads them automatically if the source maps feature has been enabled in its dev tools and they are available in the same directory as the minified CSS file they point to.

So the answer is: you don't put them in the document.